# Admob - no ad to show

Tags: java, android, admob

Hello
I try to make some example program showing ads on Android phone, and I try to test it on Emulator of v2.2
Everything in code seems to be fine, but AdListener in debugger says that:

> Response message is zero or null;
>   onFailedToReceiveAd( No ad to show).

Is there any way for it to be my fault? Did anyone encounter same problem?
Heres the code
Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.AdTest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".AdTest"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<!-- AdMobActivity definition -->
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" />
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"></uses-sdk>
<!-- AdMob SDK requires Internet permission -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and Activity code

```
package com.AdTest;
import com.google.ads.*;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest.ErrorCode;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class AdTest extends Activity implements AdListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
   AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "anonymouse");
   // Unit ID is correct, I changed it on purpose while pasting here
    adView.setAdListener(this);
    layout.addView(adView);
    AdRequest request= new AdRequest();
    adView.loadAd(request);            
  }

 public void onFailedToReceiveAd(AdView adView)
    {
        Log.d("AdListener", "onFailedToReceiveAd");
    }

    public void onFailedToReceiveRefreshedAd(AdView adView)
    {
        Log.d("AdListener", "onFailedToReceiveRefreshedAd");
    }

    public void onReceiveAd(AdView adView)
    {
        Log.d("AdListener", "onReceiveAd");
    }

    public void onReceiveRefreshedAd(AdView adView)
    {
        Log.d("AdListener", "onReceiveRefreshedAd");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
          Log.d("AdListener", "onFailedToReceiveAD");

    }

    @Override
    public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
         Log.d("AdListener", "Received succesfully");

    }
}
```

Comment: `s there any way for it to be my fault?` We don't know until we see your code.

Answer (score 2):

I have confront the same problem with

> onFailedToReceiveAd( No ad to show).

It seems AdMob not sent ad content for our app for some reasons. Even when I in testing mode there's still no ad.

I create my house ad on AdMob to verify my application. It's an easier way in development than testing mode.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented AdListener on my Activity and set it as the AdView listener, then added the following

```
    public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1)
{
    Log.d("AdMob", "Failed to receive an Ad.  Requesting a new one..." + arg1);
    arg0.stopLoading();
    arg0.loadAd(new AdRequest());

}
```

Comment: What about ciclyc redundancy? You call yourself with this code if fails - infinity loop.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too. So I changed the code to set the test mode true, then the Admob test ad started to show on the emulator.  Try this in your OnCreate() method:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);    
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "anonymouse");    
// Unit ID is correct, I changed it on purpose while pasting here     
adView.setAdListener(this);     
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
request.setTesting(true);     
adView.loadAd(request);
```

If you run this on a real device and still no ad to show, then I guess it might have something to do with Admob fill rate.

Comment: I published my app to Android Market with this implementation, after about 100 requests the real ad started showing up on the real device, even though the fill rate was low though (around 20%). This proves the code is correct, the problem is on Admob side.

Answer (score 1):

Change the test mode to true.  Note that ads will not be displayed until at least 3 access attempts are made for the day.

Comment: I'm not doubting you, but do you have a link to where it says ads are not displayed until 3 access attempts are made for the day?

Comment: sorry I don't remember where I read that, maybe in the SDK itself.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the latest admob SDK 4.0.4 doesn't display ads on 1.5 devices.

In the emulator it works fine for 1.6+, but not 1.5.

I think its from the new cross-over advertising with AdSense.  As far as I can tell the SDK now wraps a webview as the visual component of the view so it can publish the different kinds of ads.  A close look at the log shows WebView.multitouch enabled - as 1.5 doesn't support multitouch (for us developers in Java) due to Apple throwing its toys out of the pram and having a dummyspit (I understand they believe only they are allowed to use two fingers at once..) and perhaps enabling multitouch on the webview causes an internal exception and the view never gets created, and thus cannot receive the HTML reply from the admob http server.

Also see this [link](http://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/fbadced27a428cbd)

Answer (score 0):

1/ get the latest SDK version
2/ try admob demo with your publisher id
3/ try it in test mode (this should work always)
4/ try to add some sample house ads (shown when there is no other ad available)
5/ try to change your keywords

In general, admob prints detailed error to log (ID missing, activity missing in manifest etc).

Answer (score 0):

I had done the admob integration and that is run on device as well as on emulator.

so, please try below code:

I think you have to remove textview from main.xml

and  also try this:

1) Create new app on in your admob a/c
2) then simply replace the id of previous app by new one

try it bro.

Answer (score 0):

I also get this problem. You can try to customized the request, before loading. Like this:

```
AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
//re.setTesting(true);
re.setGender(AdRequest.Gender.FEMALE);
adview.loadAd(re);
```

I put my example, apk file and source code here, you can try:

[Add Google Admob in Android Application](http://android.jmsliu.com/209/add-google-admob-in-android-application.html)